# Shell Script ssh $SERVER >> EOF

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, eof

I have a handy script here that can return accounts that will expire in 7 Days or have expired. I wanted to allow this to run on multiple hosts with out putting the script on each individual host, I added the `for loop` and the `ssh $SERVER >> EOF` part but it will just run the commands off they system that is running the script.

I believe the error is with `ssh $SERVER >> EOF` but I am unsure as the syntax looks correct.

```
#!/bin/bash

for SERVER in `cat /lists/testlist`
do
  echo $SERVER

  ssh $SERVER >> EOF
    sudo cat /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f1,8 | sed /:$/d > /tmp/expirelist.txt
    totalaccounts=`sudo cat /tmp/expirelist.txt | wc -l`
    for((i=1; i<=$totalaccounts; i++ ))
    do
      tuserval=`sudo head -n $i /tmp/expirelist.txt | tail -n 1`
      username=`sudo echo $tuserval | cut -f1 -d:`
      userexp=`sudo echo $tuserval | cut -f2 -d:`
      userexpireinseconds=$(( $userexp * 86400 ))
      todaystime=`date +"%s"`
      if [[ $userexpireinseconds -ge $todaystime ]] ;
      then
        timeto7days=$(( $todaystime + 604800 ))
        if [[ $userexpireinseconds -le $timeto7days ]];
        then
          echo $username "is going to expire in 7 Days"
        fi
      else
        echo $username "account has expired"
      fi
    done
    sudo rm /tmp/expirelist.txt
  EOF
done
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here documents are started by `<< EOF` (or, better, `<< 'EOF'` to prevent the body of the here document being expanded by the (local) shell) and the end marker must be in column 1.

What you're doing is running `ssh` and appending standard output to a file EOF (`>>` is an output redirection; `<<` is an input redirection).  It is then (locally) running `sudo`, etc.  It probably fails to execute the local file `EOF` (not executable, one hopes), and likely doesn't find any other command for that either.

I think what you're after is this (where I've now replaced the back-ticks in the script with `$(...)` notation, and marginally optimized the server list generation for use with Bash):

```
#!/bin/bash

for SERVER in $(</lists/testlist)
do
  echo $SERVER

  ssh $SERVER << 'EOF'
    sudo cat /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f1,8 | sed '/:$/d' > /tmp/expirelist.txt
    totalaccounts=$(sudo cat /tmp/expirelist.txt | wc -l)
    for ((i=1; i<=$totalaccounts; i++))
    do
      tuserval=$(sudo head -n $i /tmp/expirelist.txt | tail -n 1)
      username=$(sudo echo $tuserval | cut -f1 -d:)
      userexp=$(sudo echo $tuserval | cut -f2 -d:)
      userexpireinseconds=$(( $userexp * 86400 ))
      todaystime=$(date +"%s")
      if [[ $userexpireinseconds -ge $todaystime ]]
      then
        timeto7days=$(( $todaystime + 604800 ))
        if [[ $userexpireinseconds -le $timeto7days ]]
        then
          echo $username "is going to expire in 7 Days"
        fi
      else
        echo $username "account has expired"
      fi
    done
    sudo rm /tmp/expirelist.txt
EOF
done
```

Very close, but the differences really matter!  Note, in particular, that the end marker `EOF` is in column 1 and not indented at all.

Comment: I have made the small changes you mentioned but the behavior is the same. Additionally I have noticed that for each server in the testlist it will give the following errors.
`line 7: EOF: Permission denied`
`line 29: EOF: command not found`

Comment: The 'EOF: command not found' message means you've done something wrong.  Most likely, you indented EOF, whereas I explicitly noted that the EOF must not be indented ('the end marker must be in column 1').  That said, you should be getting errors about 'here document not complete' and so on, so I'm not sure what you really tried.

Comment: Found it, I was using `>>` instead of `<<`. All is working now, thank you!!

Comment: That would also do it...when I tried the misplaced EOF, I got: `xx.sh: line 9: warning: here-document at line 4 delimited by end-of-file (wanted 'EOF')` and 
`xx.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file` (where I used a smaller test script, and `sh -s` in place of `ssh`).  Your forgetting to replace `>>` with `<<` makes more sense of the messages you said you got.

Comment: fantastic, this resolved my issue with the same problem.